# submitting string value to database returns error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to submit a product description from my dashboard to my database, however, whenever I include ", or ', in the description, It responds with the error `The string constant beginning with "' )" does not have an ending string delimiter.  SQLSTATE=42603`. I understand why that is happening, but it is necessary for me to have those in there, as some products descriptions need to say, `10" tall`, or `1' wide`, without it changing the format of the string... is there a way around this?

front end:

```
 <fieldset>
  <label for="bio">Description:</label>
  <textarea id="bio" name="description" placeholder="Enter product desc..." style="border: 1px solid black" required></textarea>
</fieldset>
<button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

backend code:

```
var size = req.query.size;
console.log(size);

var image_url = req.query.url;
//DB2 CONNETCTION FOR ADDING PRODUCTS
var addProducts =
  "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES ('" +
  req.query.item +
  "', '" +
  req.query.description +
  "', '" +
  req.query.price +
  "', '" +
  size +
  "', '" +
  image_url +
  "' )";
ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  conn.query(addProducts, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    if (err) {
      productAddedValue = false;
    } else {
      productAddedValue = true;
    }
    //RENDERING ADD PRODUCTS PAGE
    res.render("add-products", {
      page_title: "add-products",
      data: rows,
      userName: userName,
      FN: firstName,
      LN: lastName,
      CO: company,
      productAddedValue: productAddedValue,
    });

    conn.close(function () {
      console.log("closed the function /add-products");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a query builder or ORM rather than concatenating user input. This would properly escape input to prevent errors and SQL injection attacks. See [this example](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/examples/params.js#L28) from the official DB2 bindings.